# kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING with remote host

Tags: apache-kafka, digital-ocean

I installed a Zookeeper and one Kafka broker server in one of my cloud server instances, and they are working well. But when trying to connect to the remote Zookeeper server, the Kafka broker is not able to reach that IP address and port number. The firewall is also in inactive mode.

The summary is:

```
one zookeeper server - in cloud instance [146.646.64.66*]
one Kafka broker server - in cloud instance [146.646.64.66*]
two Kafka broker server - in my local PC [localhost]
```

I have updated the `zookeeper.connect` property of the local Kafka broker server's property file as follows:

```
zookeeper.connect=146.646.64.66*:2181
```

The following is the error that the CMD shows:

```
[2021-06-17 19:47:01,443] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=174.138.31.159:2181 sessionTimeout=18000 watcher=kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$ZooKeeperClientWatcher$@6736fa8d (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-06-17 19:47:01,468] INFO jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket)
[2021-06-17 19:47:01,545] INFO zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled= (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-06-17 19:47:01,553] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2021-06-17 19:47:19,557] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2021-06-17 19:47:21,663] INFO Opening socket connection to server 146.646.64.66*/146.646.64.66*:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-06-17 19:47:21,801] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 20251ms for sessionid 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-06-17 19:47:21,929] INFO Session: 0x0 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-06-17 19:47:21,929] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-06-17 19:47:21,934] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2021-06-17 19:47:21,944] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$waitUntilConnected$3(ZooKeeperClient.scala:271)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:267)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:125)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1948)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.createZkClient$1(KafkaServer.scala:431)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:456)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:191)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2021-06-17 19:47:21,982] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: You should never create a stretched Kafka cluster like this. What is the use-case?

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Comment: this is for only testing purpose. just i wanted to connect multi brokers into zookeeper.

Comment: I was running in minikube and it would crash because it timed out trying to connect to zookeeper. Turns out a lot of my system pods were not running or ready in minikube. I updated it and the connection seems to have worked with zero restarts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove all cached log files or change the directory of the log path of the server.properties file that you are going to run. the cache log files' data can be affected due to your server history.

Comment: Cache files don't affect network exceptions such as timeouts

Comment: I also wonder about that. i also faced the same problem before. after deleting log files. the error didn't come.